# undefined control sequence - \@rllanguagename

Tags: errors, lyx, amsart

I've been using LyX for a while for math typing. So far I was using the "standard article" class, and everything worked well. But when I'm trying to use an AMS article class, I get this error (even if the document is empty):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\moreL ...dL \beginL \csname from\@rllanguagename 
                                              \endcsname 
l.18 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\moreL ...dL \beginL \csname from\@rllanguagename 
                                              \endcsname 
l.18 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `HE8/cmr/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 18.
(newfile1.aux) )
```

It also says this, few lines earlier:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Hebrew' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 57.
```

This is the code that produces the problem (it happens also with an empty document):

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,hebrew]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}%
\inputencoding{latin9}hello\selectlanguage{hebrew}%

\end{document}
```

I'm using pdf(la)tex with LyX 2.1.3 on a Windows machine, Installed withe MiKTeX 2.9. Thanks.

Comment: Please post a minimum working example of code that generates this error. Please also state which TeX engine -- pdf(la)tex, xe(la)tex, or lua(la)tex -- you use.

Comment: The details are now in the question. Thank for the comment.

Comment: It seems to be a specific problem with `amsart`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another check I can do to say for sure? Can I get amsart from somewhere else?

Comment: amsart is doing some typesetting in the AtBeginDocument-hook when not every babel command has been set up. So it breaks when it encounters the `@brackets` command in `\leftmarginii`. Try `\makeatletter\def\@rllanguagename{hebrew}\makeatother`.

Comment: Thanks! OK, I tried to do this on TeXworks, and it's working (not for Hebrew, but also no errors) How can I add this to LyX\amsart permanently?

Comment: @omrikap -- regarding your last comment, about adding this permanently to lyx/amsart, can you please ask that as a new question?  (i'm about to add ulrike's comment as an answer, to get this question off the "unanswered" list.)

Answer (score 5):

@Ulrike Fischer points out that

> `amsart` is doing some typesetting in the `AtBeginDocument-hook` when
>   not every babel command has been set up. So it breaks when it
>   encounters the `@brackets` command in `\leftmarginii`. Try
>
> ```
> \makeatletter
> \def\@rllanguagename{hebrew}
> \makeatother
> ```

Comment: Since this answer entirely consists of a comment made by someone else, should it not be made Community Wiki?